# backbone render collection return one object

Tags: json, backbone.js, collections

i have problem rendering my view...the view return always the last in the json object: This is the code:

Router.js:

```
var list = new clientCollection();
var cards = new cardsView({model:list})
list.fetch({success: function (collection, response, options) {
            cards.render();
           }
});
```

Cards.js view:

```
   ....
tagName: 'section',
className: 'list',
template: Handlebars.compile(cardsTemplate),
render: function () {

                var list = this.model.toJSON(),
                    self = this,
                    wrapperHtml = $("#board"),
                    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();


                $(list).each(function (index, item) {

                    $(self.el).html(self.template({card: item}));

                    $.each(item.cards, function (i, c) {
                        var card = new cardView({model : c});

                        $(self.el).find('.list-cards').append(card.render().el);
                    });


                    fragment.appendChild(self.el);
                });

                wrapperHtml.append(fragment.cloneNode(true));
            },
    ...
```

This is my json data:

```
[
{"id":"9","name_client":"XXXXXXX","cards":[]},
{"id":"8","name_client":"XXXXXXX","cards":[{"id":"8","title":"xxxxx.it","description":"some desc","due_date":"2016-01-23","sort":"0"}]}
]
```

Can u help me to render the view?

Comment: as per you json. its 8th id data is last which is only rendered right ?

Comment: user first each like $.each(list, function (index, item) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know for sure without seeing how the view(s) are attached to the DOM, but your problem appears to be this line ...

```
$(self.el).html(self.template({card: item}));
```

That is essentially rendering each element in the collection as the *full contents of this view*, then replacing it on each iteration.  Try instead appending the contents of each template to the view's element.

Also, since you tagged this with `backbone.js` and `collections`, note that the easier, more Backbone-y way to iterate through a collection would be:

```
this.model.each(function(item) {
    // 'item' is now an instance of the Backbone.Model type 
    // contained within the collection.  Also, note the use 
    // of 'this' within the iterator function, as well as
    // this.$el within a View is automatically the same as
    // $(self.el)
    this.$el.append(this.template({ card: item });

    // ... and so on ...

    // By providing 'this' as the second argument to 'each(...)',
    // the context of the iterator function is set for you.
}, this);
```

There's a lot packed in there, so ...

- [Backbone.Collection Underscore Methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods)
- [Backbone.View this.$el](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el)